# Package colorednoise.py working in jupyter notebook but no script under the same environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment, noise

When I run the code:

```py
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Tuple
import os
import scipy.io, scipy.signal
import colorednoise as cn

def generate_pink_noise(singal_length):
    beta = 1      
    samples = singal_length  
    noise = cn.powerlaw_psd_gaussian(beta, samples)
    return noise
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...MEA_foward_model.py", line 11, in <module>
    import colorednoise as cn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorednoise'
```

Note the 'test' environment I'm using shown here when I get the error: [environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86NSS.png).
However the same code runs without error in Jupiter notebook:

```py
import colorednoise as cn
signal_length =10
beta = 1         # the exponent: 0=white noite; 1=pink noise;  2=red noise (also "brownian noise")
samples = signal_length  # number of samples to generate (time series extension)
noise = cn.powerlaw_psd_gaussian(beta, samples)
```

This image shows (see top right corner) shows that the same environment is used
[jupyter notebook output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzwpD.png). What is causing this dissonance between the two different behaviours?

Comment: maybe you have installed two Pythons 3.8 and they don't share modules. You could also check `sys.executable` to see if both use the same Python. OR if it is your module then you may run in different `Current Working Directory` (see `os.getcwd()`) and it can't find module in this folder.

Comment: I get  'C:\Anaconda\python.exe' (using the base?) for the script and 'C:\\Anaconda\\envs\\test\\python.exe' for the jupyter notbook when I print sys.executable. I'm a bit confused as to why since they're using the same environment. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: it seems you run script without environment `test`. Try run in console `C:\Anaconda\envs\test\python.exe your_script.py`. Maybe you forgot to `activate` environment before running script.